# Python Selenium can't find table

Tags: python, selenium

Why Selenium isnt finding the table in the page?

I cant figure out what is wrong in the code bellow.

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver

import time
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
prefs = {'safebrowsing.enabled': 'false', 'download.default_directory': r'C:\Users\guilh\Documents\Informes'}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

driver.get('http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/fundos-de-investimentos/fii/')

time.sleep(2)
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
print(df)
```

ERROR:

```
ValueError: No tables found
```

Comment: You want to find the table then you can get it by its xpath or id. Why are you getting the whole page source for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iframe is present on your web page. You need to switch iframe first before handling table data. Please refer below solution::

```
driver.get('http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/fundos-de-investimentos/fii/')
driver.maximize_window()
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'bvmf_iframe')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

tabel = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//table[@class="responsive"]')))

print tabel.text
```

**Note:** 
Please add belo imports

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help